# How to position google autocomplete predictions?

Tags: css, angular, google-maps-api-3

I have a table with a list of contacts as seen in the image. I also have an event that gets triggered when a row is clicked so it can show the selected contact detail (I am using angular NGIF directive to show and hide the detail)
[image]

The thing is because my google input is placed inside an NGIF block, when user expands the contact detail and tries to type in it, the predictions (pac-container) is showing on the row that I clicked (within the table) rather than underneath the google input autocomplete search box.

I tried to manipulate the css of the class `pac-container` but I couldn't figure out a way to override the css of that class.

Here is my the html of my autocomplete search box

```
<div *ngIf="showGoogleAddress" class="mg-b-10" fxLayoutGap="10px" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayout.sm="column" fxFlexFill>
          <div fxFlex>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="form-field">
              <mat-label>Google Address Search Box</mat-label>
              <input [debounceTime]="500" ngxAutocomPlace autocomplete="off" (selectedPlace)="placeChanged($event)" placeholder="ex: Phoenix, Arizona" matInput #googleAddress="matInput" >
              <mat-icon matSuffix>location_on</mat-icon>
              <mat-hint>Search for compolete address, or city</mat-hint>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>

        </div>
```

also, here is a screenshot of the entire form after expanding the detail

[image]

If the google autocomplete box was outside the NGIF, then it will render the predictions just fine without an issue. It seems that because I am using NGIF directive, the google component is not able to determine the right position (calculate the right position) to render its predictions..

When I tried

```
.pac-container {
  position: absolute !important;
  z-index: 100000;
}
```

it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to go with a DOM Manipulation way using JS.. so I added a (keyUp) event handler on google search box with a method to calculate the position like the following:

```
adjustResPosition() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        var gSearchBar = document.getElementById('googleBar');
        var topPos = (gSearchBar?.getBoundingClientRect().top || 0) + window.scrollY + 25;
        var leftPos = (gSearchBar?.getBoundingClientRect().left || 0) + window.scrollX;

        var gPreds = document.querySelector('.pac-container');
        gPreds?.setAttribute('style', `top: ${topPos}px; position: absolute!important; width: auto; left: ${leftPos}px`);
      }, 600);
    }
```

The reason why I put setTimeout to 600ms is because I have a debounce 500 ms each until it grabs the next predictions and put it in the `pac-container` div

Note, this is not an optimal solution and it can be improved with `ViewChild` or `ElementRef`

Comment: Hi, I will fix this and add some customisation examples to the readme of NgxAutocomPlace directive soon :) Feel free to open an issue on the github page !